# T-SQL Recursive CTE with Multiple Parent Items

Tags: sql, recursion

All of the recursive CTE examples I can find use essentially the same scenario.  They all traverse up or down an org chart.  My CTE works great for parent/child relationships that are one-to-one, like where one employee has one manager, but I have a table where a child can have multiple parents.  What I want is a disctinct list of parent IDs stemming from one child.

If you're interested in specifics, I'm recursing through the predecessors of a particular task in an MS Project file.  I want to start with a particular milestone and trace all the way up to the top of the file in order to find any predecessors that may be affecting the milestone.  As you may know, a task can have multiple predecessors.

My relationships look like this:

**tblTasks**

```
child    parent
3        1
16       1
25       1
25       3
25       16
26       1
26       3
27       25
27       26
```

Here is my CTE:

```
;WITH ProjectTrace(Task)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition (This is task 27)
    SELECT t.parent AS Task
    FROM #tblTasks t
    WHERE t.child = 27

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member definition (This is everything that hooks into 27 via predecessors)
    SELECT t.parent AS Task
    FROM #tblTasks t
    INNER JOIN ProjectTrace trace
        ON t.child = trace.Task
)
SELECT * FROM ProjectTrace ORDER BY Task
```

**I want to supply task #27 to the query and get only 1,3,16,25,26 in my resultset**.  However, because of the way the recursion works, my resultset looks like this:

```
Task
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
16
25
26
```

If you look at the relationships, I guess that makes sense.  I can always change the select a the end to a select distinct, but when I get really deep in the project, say task number 500, it returns millions of records.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Missing a `DISTINCT` on the last select?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this... what is the problem?  Add the distinct and you are gtg

Comment: As I said in my original post:

"I can always change the select a the end to a select distinct, but when I get really deep in the project, say task number 500, it returns millions of records."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `distinct` is good way to do this. You can also check iterative insert solution:

```
declare @Temp table(Task int primary key)

insert into @Temp
select distinct parent from Table1 where child = 27

while 1 = 1
begin
    insert into @Temp
    select distinct T.parent
    from Table1 as T
    where
        exists (select * from @Temp as TT where TT.Task = T.child) and
        not exists (select * from @Temp as TT where TT.Task = T.parent)

    if @@rowcount = 0 break
end

select * from @Temp
```

don't know if it would be faster, check it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks Roman!  That's perfect and it runs WAY faster than the CTE.  Would love it if you'd explain what it's doing.

Comment: @KevinSlane basically is't just inserting in the resultset parent of the given child and then run infinite loop where checking if there any records where child in `@Temp` id and parent are not, and then inserting if there're such a records.

Comment: Well thank you!  It really got me over the proverbial hump.  Working great for us!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a better performing option than `DISTINCT`.

You can't use a `LEFT JOIN` to limit to where the trace.Task `IS NULL`, you can't `GROUP BY`.  I think `DISTINCT` is the way to go.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  If that's the case, I'm afraid the CTE solution isn't going to work for me.  I'm not sure if there is a better one, but I can't publish a report that takes several minutes to run.  Well, I **CAN**, but I won't make many friends that way. :)